# hook_menu_alter() is not working

Tags: routes, hooks

I have implemented `hook_menu_alter()` in a module I have created. I have printed something inside that function call but nothing shows up, though the function `hook_init()` is executed from the same module. The output of `hook_init()` shows up in the page, but not from the `hook_menu_alter()` even after clearing the cache.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this issue?

```
function mymodule_init(){
print "here";
}

function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
print "I am here";
return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` are not always invoked; they are invoked only when Drupal rebuilds the menus, such as when a module is enabled, disabled, installed, or uninstalled, or when the Drupal cache is cleared.

[Anatomy of hook_menu](http://drupal.org/node/300997) reports the following sentence:

> `hook_menu()` is called rarely, such as when modules are enabled. If you edit a module’s `hook_menu()`, you must visit admin/build/modules for the changes to take effect.

The function that invokes the implementations of `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` is [`menu_router_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7), which contains the following code (in Drupal 7).

```php
$callbacks = array();
foreach (module_implements('menu') as $module) {
  $router_items = call_user_func($module . '_menu');
  if (isset($router_items) && is_array($router_items)) {
    foreach (array_keys($router_items) as $path) {
      $router_items[$path]['module'] = $module;
    }
    $callbacks = array_merge($callbacks, $router_items);
  }
}
drupal_alter('menu', $callbacks);
list($menu, $masks) = _menu_router_build($callbacks);
_menu_router_cache($menu);

return array($menu, $masks);
```

The function is called by [`menu_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7), which is then called by:

- [`drupal_flush_all_caches()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/7)
- [`menu_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_enable/7), the implementation of `hook_enable()`
- [`menu_uninstall()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.install/function/menu_uninstall/7), the implementation of `hook_uninstall()`
- 12 other functions, and 1 method

`drupal_flush_all_caches()` is invoked by [`system_modules_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_modules_submit/7), which is the submission handler for the module page where modules are enabled, and disabled; every time a module is enable, or disabled, the menu is rebuilt, and both the menu hooks are invoked.

Answer (score 3):

In short: It does.

A print will most like not be visible, because of the timing of the function call. If you use `drupal_set_message`, you should see a message displayed.

The reason is that the menu is rebuilt as part of the action on the form submit which happens before the page is actually rendered. `drupal_set_message` is instead stored in the users session, so it will persist a page refresh, much like error messages on form validation.

Also `hook_menu_alter` should not return anything, instead you change the referenced variable. This is how all drupal's `*_alter` hooks work.

Answer (score 1):

in `*_alter` hooks the argument is passed by reference (in this case `$items`), so rather than returning anything just print directly from the alter function.

```
echo"<pre>";
print_r($items);
```

and clear cache.

You will able to see the whole array.